# Reading all CSV files in current working directory into pandas with correct filenames

Tags: csv, pandas, for-loop

I'm trying to use a loop to read in multiple CSVs (for now but mix of that and xls in the future).

I'd like each data frame in pandas to be the same name excluding file extension in my folder.

```
import os 
import pandas as pd


files = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir( os.curdir ) )
files #   this shows a list of the files that I want to use/have in my directory- they are all CSVs if that matters

# i want to load these into pandas data frames with the corresponding filenames

 # not sure if this is the right approach....
 # but what is wrong is the variable is named 'weather_today.csv'... i need to drop the .csv or .xlsx or whatever it might be

for each_file in files:
    frame = pd.read_csv( each_file)
    each_file = frame
```

Bernie seems to be great but one problem:

```
or each_file in files:
    frame = pd.read_csv(each_file)
    filename_only = os.path.splitext(each_file)[0]
   # Right below I am assigning my looped data frame the literal variable name of "filename_only" rather than the value that filename_only represents
   #rather than what happens if I print(filename_only)
    filename_only = frame
```

for example if my two files are weather_today, earthquakes.csv (in that order) in my files list, then both 'earthquakes' and 'weather' will not be created.

however, if I simply type  'filename_only' and click the enter key in python - then I will see the earthquake dataframe.  If I have 100 files, then the last data frame name in the list loop will be titled 'filename_only' and the other 99 won't because the previous assignments are never made and the 100th one overwrites them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`os.path.splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) for this to "split the pathname path into a pair (root, ext) such that root + ext == path, and ext is empty or begins with a period and contains at most one period."

```
for each_file in files:
    frame = pd.read_csv(each_file)
    filename_only = os.path.splitext(each_file)[0]
    filename_only = frame
```

As asked in a comment we would like a way to filter for just CSV files so you can do something like this:

```
files = [file for file in os.listdir( os.curdir ) if file.endswith(".csv")]
```

Comment: wow very simple.  if you don't mind asking with my   first part - files = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir( os.curdir ) )
 ----- is there a way to specify this to be a particular extension.  I am new to this sort of thing...

Comment: Isn't what you are doing just overwriting the file name stored in `filename_only` by the DataFrame? It will be overwritten in the next run of the loop. Kind of don't see the point of that.

Comment: I tried this again and it doesn't seem to be working.  I think it worked the first time since i had read them in by csv.  I restarted my session and I still get all the files as 'today_weather.csv' names rather than today_weather

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary to store your frames:

```
frames = {}

for each_file in files:
    frames[os.path.splitext(each_file)[0]] = pd.read_csv(each_file)
```

Now you can get the DataFrame of your choice with:

```
frames[filename_without_ext]
```

Simple, right? Be careful about RAM usage though, reading a bunch of files can quickly fill up system memory and cause a crash.

Comment: Yes, but why does this work and the approach above not work?  When I try using an intermediate print step above I get a name but the last part of the answer above doesn't seem to work with the assignment...   Also I would like to have them loaded directory into memory rather than in a list.

Comment: It is a dictionary, not a list. There is a big difference between the two. Are you sure you got the code from @bernie's answer correctly copied? And what you are asking cannot be strictly done. You cannot declare variables unless your program writes code then executes it. The code being executed cannot be modified in Python. The only thing you can do is modify your variables. A dictionary allows for named keys, to which you attach values. That is what my answer does, and that is the easiest way you can kind of answer your question.

Comment: OK, I understand that part but I believe what is going wrong is the word FILENAME_ONLY is being used as the spelling of the variable  aka "FILENAME_ONLY" = weather_data.csv      rather than the FILENAME_ONLY 'carrying' the extraction of the spelling weather_data and thus setting weather_data = weather_data.csv

Comment: You are spinning me in circles! Let the code talk. Can you edit your question with @bernie's answer and output, and expected output? That would be very helpful.